# Windows 7 installer for Adobe Acrobat Reader for viewing PDF files is broken

Tags: windows-7, pdf, adobe-acrobat, adobe-reader

Below is a screen shot I received in step 3 of 3 during the Adobe Acrobat Reader installer.  In step 1, I had to choose my operating system, which is Windows 7.

[image]

Before clicking the "Install Now" button, I unchecked the "Yes" checkboxes to avoid advertisements.

I normally use Google's PDF viewer in gmail, but I'd like a reliable Windows PDF viewer.  Is anyone aware of one that works and is free, or knows how to get Adobe's installer to work?

https://get.adobe.com/reader/

EDIT:

Event Viewer error message:

> Product: Adobe Reader XI (11.0.10) - Update 'Adobe Reader XI
>   (11.0.10)' could not be installed. Error code 1603. Windows Installer
>   can create logs to help troubleshoot issues with installing software
>   packages. Use the following link for instructions on turning on
>   logging support: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=23127

Comment: Are you running the installer as an administrator?

Answer (score 1):

Solution to my specific problem:

Per @Ouroborus answer....

1. I didn't have Google Desktop installed, so that wasn't it
2. Deleted all sub-folders under C:\WINDOWS\Temp
3. When the file downloaded, I chose Open, and right clicked, to "Run as Administrator" (per @Burgi)

Sounds like it was either #2 or #3 that solved it.  Or a combination of both.

Answer (score 0):

#### Update 'Adobe Reader XI (11.0.10)' could not be installed. Error code 1603.

> Like most Windows applications, Acrobat and Reader use Microsoft Windows Installer technology for installing updates. If the update fails, you can get one of the following Microsoft Installer errors.

...

> 1603 A fatal error occurred during installation or #*AdobeError*#1603
>
> Shut down Microsoft Office and all web browsers. Then, in Acrobat or
>   Reader, choose Help > Check for Updates.
>
> See also [Error 1603 | Install | CS3, CS4 products](https://helpx.adobe.com/creative-suite/kb/error-1603-install-cs3-cs4.html).

Source [Acrobat Help / Fix Windows errors that occur during Acrobat Reader update](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/kb/update-errors-acrobat-reader-windows.html)